# Parse an XML into a database with phonegap/Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

Hey everyone I was would greatly appreciate some help here, I am trying to parse an XML and put the results into a database for an app I am working on(Phonegap/JQuery mobile app). Can someone show me how to do this inside of a JS function?

I understand the parsing process for the XML however I am a little lost on storing it locally into the SQLlite database that phonegap lets you access. Here is the XML I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <orders>
    <order>
        <orderId>123456789</orderId>
        <city>Cincinnati</city>
        <state>Ohio</state>
        <zip>45451</zip>
    </order>
 </orders>
```

Here is a JS function to parse this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testOrders.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('order').each(function(){
        orderId = $(this).find("orderId").text();
        city = $(this).find("city").text();
        state = $(this).find("state").text();
        zip = $(this).find("zip").text();
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('<div>');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('<h3>'OrderId: '+ orderId + '</h3>');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('<p>');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('City: '+ city + '<br />');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('State: '+ state + '<br />');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('Zip: '+ zip +'<br />');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('</p>');
         $("#acceptedOrdersContent").append('</div>');
            });
        }
     });
 });
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the DB:

```
var db = openDatabase('PhoneGap_db', '1.0', '', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Create the table:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (id unique, city, state, zip)');
});
```

Insert into table:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO orders (id, city, state, zip) VALUES (orderId,city,state,zip)');
});
```

it will be best to put the INSERT inside the AJAX's callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testOrders.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('order').each(function(){
        orderId = $(this).find("orderId").text();
        city = $(this).find("city").text();
        state = $(this).find("state").text();
        zip = $(this).find("zip").text();
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
           tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO orders (id, city, state, zip) VALUES      (orderId,city,state,zip)');
        });
            });
        }
     });
```

Good luck!

Comment: dod_basim thanks for your quick reply, I did have another question for you. How would I display these now that they are in the database?