# Error parsing XML into SQLite DB with JQuery: all rows have same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, sqlite

This is an update to my previous question on a similar subject. Using [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745478/parse-an-xml-into-a-database-with-phonegap-jquery-ajax) as a guide, I am trying to read from an xml file `orders.xml` to a database table, `orders`. The problem I am having is that only the final XML object is added to the database.

## [Update: Now with Plunkr!](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9JvnSqDkg6dZm2rEnrr?p=preview)

I have added 6 "orders" objects to the XML, like so:

```
   <orders>
      <order>
          <orderId>123456789</orderId>
          <city>Cincinnati</city>
          <state>Ohio</state>
          <zip>45451</zip>
      </order>
      <order>
          <orderId>99999999999</orderId>
          <city>Oz</city>
          <state>Michigan</state>
          <zip>9999</zip>
      </order>
   </orders>
```

The final object has city "Stockholm" and state "Sweden".

First I drop the table, and then I open the DB connection like this:

```
     db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (id UNIQUE, city, state, zip)',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);
            },errorHandler,successCallBack);

            parseXMLtoDB();
            ListDBValues();
        }
```

I parse in the XML like this:

```
       function parseXMLtoDB() {
            var orderId, city, state, zip;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "xml/orders.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('order').each(function(){
                        orderId = $(this).find("orderId").text();
                        city = $(this).find("city").text();
                        state = $(this).find("state").text();
                        zip = $(this).find("zip").text();

                        db.transaction(function (tx) {
                            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO orders (id, city, state, zip) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [orderId, city, state, zip]);
                        });
                        console.log(orderId, city, state, zip);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

and then finally I view the data like this:

```
       function ListDBValues() {

            $('#lbUsers').html('');

            db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM orders;', [],
                        function(transaction, result) {
                            if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                                    console.log(row);
                                    $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' +
                                            row.id + ' ' + row.city + ' ' + row.state);
                                }
                            }
                        },errorHandler);
            },errorHandler,nullHandler);

            return;
        }
```

If I run all of this, the console.log of all the XML variables in `parseXMLtoDB()` prints out the correct values for each order, but only the final line is added to the DB and displayed by `ListDBValues`. If I remove the flag `UNIQUE` from `CREATE TABLE orders(id UNIQUE`, then I get that same record 6 times:

```
 <span id="lbUsers"><br>4444444444444 Stockholm Sweden<br>4444444444444 Stockholm Sweden<br>4444444444444 Stockholm Sweden<br>4444444444444 Stockholm Sweden<br>4444444444444 Stockholm Sweden<br>4444444444444 Stockholm Sweden</span>
```

So the `each` is running 6 times, and the variables have the correct values (as seen on the console.log), but either the same value is being with `INSERT INTO` sent every time, OR the previous values are being overwritten by `INSERT INTO`.

Can somebody see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Apparently yes- I didn't know I could do WebDB stuff on Plunkr, but here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/z9JvnSqDkg6dZm2rEnrr?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vars should be declared inside the each function. Try this:

**PLNKER Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y4SYYcwHhWLRWzxNEDSO**

```
function parseXMLtoDB() {

  $.get('orders.xml', function(xml) {   //simple way than your way

    $(xml).find("order").each(function() {

      var orderId, city, state, zip;   // Should be here

      orderId = $(this).find("orderId").text();
      city = $(this).find("city").text();
      state = $(this).find("state").text();
      zip = $(this).find("zip").text();

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO orders (id, city, state, zip) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [orderId, city, state, zip]);
      });

      console.log(orderId, city, state, zip);

    });

  });

}
```